# What's the GUID of the docked "Find" window in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, envdte

I'm trying to close the docked find window in Visual Studio 2019 via a DTE script.

This is the window I'm talking about:
[Image of the window I'm talking about here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6UxJ.jpg)

I thought it would be "vsWindowKindFindReplace" but I just get a null when I try to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to automate a task of some sort.

I'm not familiar with DTE.  So it might be easier to do it with that.

If you use Spy++, you'll see that the "Find" control is not an HWND.  VS just has a single window and custom draws everything.  However, if you use the [Inpsect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) tool, you'll find that the close button on the Find control does have an accessibility ID - "**CloseButton**" . And you can programmatically navigate the Visual Studio accessibility tree to find it and click it

[image]

Comment: Yep, I tried to spy it and couldn't.  Do you happen to know how you focus on and click via an accessibility ID in javascript?  I'm trying to close a bunch of specific windows in visual studio with a press of esc.